# My Mongo Express container cannot comment to My Mongo Database container

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, mongo-express

My goal is to build a Mongo database with its express using Docker.
I am using the terminal.

I created the network.
`docker network create mongo`

Then, I put this command.\

> docker run --detach
> --name mongodatabaseimage
> --network mongo
> --publish 27017:27017
> --mount type=bind,source="$(pwd)/containers/mongodb/databases",target=/data/db
> --env MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME="DatabaseAdmin"
> --env MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD="0112213949Ibrahim"
> mongo:4.4.20-rc0

I want a  required authentication to connect to the database, so I put these variables: `MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME`, `MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD`.

When I try to build the Express container using:\

> docker run -it
> --name mongoexpress
> --network mongo
> -p 8081:8081 
> -e ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER=mongodatabaseimage
> -e ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME=DatabaseAdmin 
> -e ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD=0112213949Ibrahim 
> -e ME_CONFIG_BASICAUTH_USERNAME=admin 
> -e ME_CONFIG_BASICAUTH_PASSWORD=2213949ib 
> -e ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ENABLE_ADMIN=true 
> mongo-express:1.0.0-alpha.4

I receive this error:

> (node:6) [MONGODB DRIVER] Warning: Current Server Discovery and Monitoring engine is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new Server Discover and Monitoring engine, pass option { useUnifiedTopology: true } to the MongoClient constructor.
> Could not connect to database using connectionString: mongodb://DatabaseAdmin:0112213949Ibrahim@mongodatabaseimage:27017/"
> (node:6) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [mongodatabaseimage:27017] on first connect [MongoError: Authentication failed.
> at Connection.messageHandler (/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connection.js:364:19)
> at Connection.emit (events.js:314:20)
> at processMessage (/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connection.js:456:10)
> at Socket. (/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connection.js:625:15)
> at Socket.emit (events.js:314:20)
> at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:297:12)
> at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:272:9)
> at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:213:10)
> at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:188:23) {
> ok: 0,
> code: 18,
> codeName: 'AuthenticationFailed'
> }]
> at Pool. (/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/topologies/server.js:441:11)
> at Pool.emit (events.js:314:20)
> at /node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/pool.js:564:14
> at /node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/pool.js:1000:11
> at callback (/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connect.js:75:5)
> at /node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connect.js:158:27
> at /node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/auth/scram.js:110:14
> at _callback (/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connection.js:333:7)
> at Connection.messageHandler (/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connection.js:364:9)
> at Connection.emit (events.js:314:20)
> at processMessage (/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connection.js:456:10)
> at Socket. (/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connection.js:625:15)
> at Socket.emit (events.js:314:20)
> at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:297:12)
> at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:272:9)
> at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:213:10)
> (node:6) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
> (node:6) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

- I tried assigning the default port to 8080 using `-p 8080:27017` to the database container, and changed the corresponding variable in the express container.
- I tried changing the containers' names.
- My node application is connecting directly without an authentication, which is a security Issue I trying to solve. `mongodb://192.168.134.128:27017/messages`